# Response not displayed ID screen?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm trying to make a quiz response as HW. The response I typed is supposed to come up on screen but it doesn't. I checked multiple times what went wrong within lines '15' and '17' using function response(). I haven't found anything wrong and need help with debugging and writing the proper syntax.

Is there anything that needs rewriting?
thank you.

I tried multiple times checking syntax errors.

```js
function responseYes() {
  document.getElementById('screen').InnerHTML = "You are correct!"
}

function responseNo() {
  document.getElementById('screen').InnerHTML = "You are wrong~~"
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#613AAB, #613);
  color: antiquewhite;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

#screen {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #E8C8F0;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 1%
}

.Answers {
  width: 47%;
  font-size: 13pt;
  color: darkred;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  float: left;
  margin: .15%;
  padding: 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.Answers p {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3% 0;
}

.Answers:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="screen">
    <h1>Quiz Mania</h1>
    <h2>Who wants to rap with kermit?</h2>
    <a href="#" onClick="responseYes()">
      <div class="Answers">
        <p>Me</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onClick="responseNo()">
      <div class="Answers">
        <p>A dog pissing at outside</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onClick="responseNo()">
      <div class="Answers">
        <p>space</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onClick="responseYes()">
      <div class="Answers">
        <p>pencil</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
    body,html{width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; background-image:linear-gradient(#613AAB,#613); color:antiquewhite; font-weight:normal;}
    h1,h2{font-weight:normal; text-align: center;}
    #screen{width:80%; border:1px solid #E8C8F0; margin:auto; display:table; padding: 1%}
    .Answers{width:47% ; font-size:13pt; color:darkred; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.5); float:left; margin:.15%; padding: 1%; border-radius: 5px;}
    .Answers p{position: relative; margin: 3% 0;}
    .Answers:hover{background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)}
</style>
<script>
function responseNo() {
  document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "You are wrong~~";
}

function responseYes() {
  document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = "You are correct!";
}
    </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="screen">
    <h1>Quiz Mania</h1>
        <h2>Who wants to rap with kermit?</h2>
        <a href="#" onclick="responseYes()"><div class="Answers"><p>Me</p></div></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="responseNo()"><div class="Answers"><p>A dog pissing at outside</p></div></a>
        <a href="#" onClick="responseNo()"><div class="Answers"><p>space</p></div></a>
        <a href="#" onClick="responseYes()"><div class="Answers"><p>pencil</p></div></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will help you out:)

It was because of capital `I` in `InnerHTML`